# Creating buttons that retrieve files then setting text-boxes to the path of those files

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am kind of stuck. I am trying to create a python program in which when `Button1` is clicked, it asks for a text file that has IPs. Once the text file is retrieved, I would like to set `textbox1` to the path of this text file. Then when `Button2` is clicked, the user is asked to browse an .exe file. Once the .exe file is retrieved, again `textbox2's` text is set to the .exe file's path. After this when the user clicks the "run" button, .exe files start running based on the number of IPs in textfile. If there are 2 IPs in the text file, then 2 .exe files will start running, the first .exe file will run with IP1 and the second will run with IP2. Note that I am new to python.

Here is my code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


ipFilePath = ''
exeFilePath = ''

#FUNCTIONS
def browsefunc(): #browse button to search for files
   ipFilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
   return ipFilePath

def browsefunc2(): #browse button to search for files
   exeFilePath = filedialog.askopenfilename()
   return exeFilePath

def run():
  with open(ipFilePath) as f:
        for each_ip in f.readlines():
            subprocess.Popen([exeFilePath, each_ip.rstrip()], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            time.sleep(2)
#GUI

root = Tk()

root.title('Map_Launcher')
root.geometry("698x150")

mf = Frame(root)
mf.pack()

f1 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250) #file1
f1.pack(fill=X)
f2 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250) #file2
f2.pack(fill=X)
f4 = Frame(mf, width=600, height=250) #run button
f4.pack()

ipFilePath = StringVar()
exeFilePath = StringVar()

Label(f1,text="Select file 1 (Only txt files)").grid(row=0, column=0, 
sticky='e') #file1 button
entry1 = Entry(f1, width=50, textvariable=ipFilePath)
entry1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)

Label(f2,text="Select file 2 (Only exe files)").grid(row=0, column=0, 
sticky='e') #file2 button
entry2 = Entry(f2, width=50, textvariable=exeFilePath)
entry2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky='we',columnspan=25)


Button(f1, text="Browse", command=browsefunc).grid(row=0, column=27, 
sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)#file1 button
Button(f2, text="Browse", command=browsefunc2).grid(row=0, column=27, 
sticky='ew', padx=8, pady=4)#file2 button
Button(f4, text="Run", width=32, command=lambda: run).grid(sticky='ew', 
padx=10, pady=10)#run button


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

Missing `import subprocess`.

`ipFilePath` and `exeFilePath` are assigned twice: first empty string, then `StringVar()`.  Better remove the assignment to empty string.

Assign value to `StringVar` should use the `.set()` function:

```
def browsefunc():
    ipFilePath.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("IP file","*.txt")]))

def browsefunc2():
    exeFilePath.set(filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Program file", "*.exe")]))
```

To get the value of `StringVar` should use `.get()` function and better use `subprocess.communicate()` instead of `sleep()`:

```
def run():
    with open(ipFilePath.get()) as f:
        for each_ip in f.readlines():
            p = subprocess.Popen([exeFilePath.get(), each_ip.rstrip()], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            p.communicate()
```

Just assign `run` to `command` argument for "Run" button:

```
Button(f4, text="Run", width=32, command=run).grid(...)
```

Comment: I am getting NameError: name 'ipFilePath' is not defined